# Center custom check drawables

Tags: android, android-drawable, xml-drawable

check_green.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:state_checked="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/check_ok" />
      <item android:state_checked="false" 
          android:drawable="@drawable/check_no"/>

    </selector>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/ckActionSelect"
    android:layout_width="60dip"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
    android:button="@drawable/check_green"/>
```

[image]

the problem is the size of png drawable, the drawable is smaller than 60dip 
is there any way to make it centred

any help will be apreciated

thanks in advance

Comment: ... could you make it a little clearer what the question asks?!

Comment: ... could you make it a little clearer what the question asks?! Why do you set it 60 dip wide and tall, instead of using "wrap_content"?

Comment: I set it to 60 dip because its in a list view that have a click event 
and if the user try to check it an misses it does somthing else than checking it 
the size of the png is 22 dp its too small so I try to put the button bigger to ensure selection.

Comment: actually I try to reuse this png without having a copy f it with more transparent border

Comment: Now, what does the question ask, really? If it's possible to move the picture to the center of the control? But why a CheckBox, if you use no text? A ToggleButton could bemore appropriate, then.

Comment: If the colored part of your picture has an offset (i.e. it's to the far left side), you'll never center it. It would be better to have a smaller image in a bigger container (you can always center the picture in its container)

Comment: how can I have a drawable container that containes a smaller one centred in it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46166/discussion-between-simo-and-tobor)